# Combining Trello boards

Tags: trello

I am ultimately responsible for multiple projects running simultaneously and could benefit from a view of multiple projects in one Trello board. My individual project managers don’t need this view; the individual project managers only need to see their own project.  Is there a way to collapse boards together?

Answer (score 8):

There isn't a way to collapse boards together.

There have been a lot of requests for a view that combines all your cards across all boards. There is a card for it here: https://trello.com/c/UOIrt48P

Comment: It says Shipped in July '12

Answer (score 1):

in the last few years I worked a lot with Trello and always missed a view to see several lists (and their cards) of different boards (aka projects) on the same page. There are some tools, which enhance the possibilites to plan tasks on Trello, like https://placker.com for instance. Still I wanted something different.

That is why I created an Open Source solution for this use case: https://github.com/natterstefan/react-trello-multiboard.

React-Trello-Multiboard is an open source app displaying multiple cards of several Trello boards and lists. The cards and lists can be filtered by people (eg. only you or a group of people). Additionally, you can even use the app to plan ahead and display the tasks of upcoming weeks (aka "sprints").

Visit https://multiboardfortrello.com/ for more details and a live example.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just hit on this idea:
create a "Board of Boards".

I assume each project will also move through certain phases (i.e. Lists).

Each project get's a card. The card's title is the name of the project, for easy identification.
For the description: get the project specific board link (available from board menu). Use that link as the description.

Voila - with a little bit of elbow grease initially, you have a meta-board that can show you the current high level situation of your projects, with links to the relevant detail boards.

Only "blech" part is you have to open the project card to get at the board link.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

Give a try to: [This github repo](https://github.com/GustavePate/mergetrelloboards)

I wrote it in an attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: Without the link this answer has no information in it. While the app you've written very well might solve the problem, the name of the app isn't even included here which would be helpful if the link stopped working. This could be a good answer if the name of the app was given and *how* it solves the issue is described.